# I am trying to install package manipulate : message = not available for r 3.1.1

Tags: r

windows 7 -pro 
r studio 0.98.945
r 3.1.1

I am trying to install manipulate:
 install.packages("manipulate").

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘manipulate’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

is this package not available or is something wrong in my machine or how to get it ?

thanks for all update/help
best regards, Guy Przytula

Answer (score 3):

It's not on CRAN. It's usually installed as part of the RStudio install process. I'd suggest to re-install RStudio.

Another possibility is [offered](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200858786-Manipulate-package-not-installing-correctly) by the RStudio support:

> 1.) The easiest workaround is to just install the package manually from its location in Program Files - you can zip up the C:\Program
>   Files\RStudio\R\library\manipulate folder and install it using
>   install.packages() - this will get the manipulate package installed
>   and running.

If that doesn't solve your issues, you should post at the RStudio support forum.